# obtaining page title from wordpress function previous_post_link()

Tags: php, wordpress, function, anchor, title

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my `previous_post_link` and `next_post_link`'s to have title attributes.

I'm passing them along like this:

```
<div class="previous <?php if(!get_previous_post()){ echo 'inactive'; }?>">
     <?php previous_post_link('%link', true); ?>
</div>              

<div class="next <?php if(!get_next_post()){ echo 'inactive'; }?>">                     
     <?php next_post_link('%link', true); ?>                
</div>
```

Optimally, I'd love to get this as an output:

```
<a href="previous/post/page.html" title="That posts title">previous post</a>
```

Is there a parameter that I'm missing? Or is something like this not achieveable?

edit: for clarification

Answer (score 1):

in wordpress
`posts_nav_link()`, displays both the Previous and Next links, 
or if you want both previous and next post link seperately,

here is the code,

```
 <?php previous_post(); ?>
```

it displays text "previous post:" as link along with post title.

without a post title,

```
 <?php previous_post('%','&laquo; Previous', 'no'); ?>
```

To display text, like arrows («), at the beginning of the previous post link and at the end of the next post link so it looks like:

```
<?php previous_post('&laquo; &laquo; %', '', 'yes'); ?>
| <?php next_post('% &raquo; &raquo; ', '', 'yes'); ?>
```

Comment: awesome thanks for the response. Sort of what I'm looking for, although I don't know if I was clear enough. What I had before was working fine, very similar to what you had posted.

Although I'm looking for something that will output

<a href="previous/post/path.html"  TITLE="The Previous Post Title">Previous</a>

Any ideas how I can get the title in the tag?
edit: fixed some formatting issues

Comment: this is exactly what i've posted mate, have a look here,
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post ,

Comment: hm, perhaps I am doing something wrong. Don't get me wrong, the code works, but it still isn't pulling in the title attribute. thanks for your time, I'll investigate the documentation some more.

Answer (score 0):

OK, then have a look at this one,

http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/04/23/wordpress-title-attributes/

and this one,

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13044/how-can-i-add-title-attributes-to-next-and-previous-post-link-functions

These links has been found on google, and it exactly answers what you're asking , so its always better to do some search before raising it as a new question.